# namespace for 'IPermissionStateManager'

Tags: c#, permissions, namespaces, abp

I think earlier this PermissionChecker was there in Volo.Abp.Authorization but now its moved to Volo.Abp.Authorization.Abstractions.

Similar problem with IPermissionStateManager  earlier it was not giving error, I think they have moved to different namespace.

Please can you help in referring IPermissionChecker and IPermissionStateManager interfaces.

Thanks
Siva

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `IPermissionChecker` => [Volo.Abp.Authorization.Permissions](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/dev/framework/src/Volo.Abp.Authorization.Abstractions/Volo/Abp/Authorization/Permissions/IPermissionChecker.cs)
- `IPermissionStateManager` is deleted, see from [here](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/commit/24498a052d7fb2900db45e45023bd3054e6fe2f3#diff-8fcfefd8fe6ba9fcb8402ee52dba05d8437c02d0441ee369646c8da75ff5c82c).
- You can use [`ISimpleStateCheckerManager`](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/dev/framework/src/Volo.Abp.Core/Volo/Abp/SimpleStateChecking/ISimpleStateCheckerManager.cs) instead of `IPermissionStateManager`.

> Example [usage](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/commit/24498a052d7fb2900db45e45023bd3054e6fe2f3#diff-129221a43cfd95d279bc0fca0a20ee7a9bb6a50c200231a01fcbc9852a537e17)